# Accessing sqlite datastore from command line

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been accessing the traditional datastore from the command line as follows:

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
from google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub import DatastoreFileStub

os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']="myapp"
apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy=apiproxy_stub_map.APIProxyStubMap()
stubname, stub = 'datastore_v3', DatastoreFileStub(os.environ["APPLICATION_ID"], Datastore, "/")  
apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.RegisterStub(stubname, stub)
```

I've upgraded to the sqlite datastore and need to update the stub (and maybe stubname), presumably with DatastoreSqliteStub, but can't seem to initialise it; any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "can't seem to initialize it"? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little module I often reuse in my AppEngine projects: [ae.py](https://gist.github.com/1136937)

It lets me just do:

```
import ae
ae.connect_local_datastore()
```

at the top of scripts. or with remote_api setup you can also do:

```
ae.connect_remote_datastore()
```

A simple console.py script that makes use of this can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/1136958)

Hope they help.